# Coefficient of a Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the coefficient of $x^2$ in the Taylor series about $x=0$ for $f(x)=e^{−x^2}$.

$$
f(0) = 1
$$

$$
(x - 0) \frac{dx}{dy} = -2 x^2 e^{-x^2}
$$

Solution is given as -1. But I can not determine how to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you evaluate your second expression at $x=0$ it vanishes, you need to calculate the next term

$$
\left.\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}\right|_{x=0} = \left.e^{-x^2} (-2 + 4 x^2)\right|_{x=0} = -2
$$

Therefore

$$
f(x) = f(0) + (x-0)\left.\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=0} + \frac{1}{2}(x-0)^2\left.\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}\right|_{x=0} + \cdots = 1 -x^2 + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

Taylor expansion of $e^{-x^2}$ is

$$e^{-x^2} = 1 -x^2+x^4/2! + \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{-x^2} = 1 - x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2!} + \ldots$$

Hence the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-1$

You just have to remember about the series of the exponential function:

$$e^{f(x)} = 1 + f(x) + \frac{f^2(x)}{2!} + \frac{f^3(x)}{3!} + \ldots$$

at $x_0 = 0$

And in general

$$e^{f(x)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!}(x - x_0)^k$$

Comment: Hi, sorry to comment here, but I was writing an answer to your questions about Galois theory and quintics when you deleted it, and I think you might find it interesting (I think the linked duplicate does not answer quite the same question).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Hì! Sorry for having deleted it, I thought my question really was a duplicate! I undeleted the question, you can find it here ^_^  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336038/layman-explanation-resolvent-formula-for-equations-of-degree-n-4?noredirect=1#comment4809477_2336038